The entire JS file gets executed when I use the require() function. Why?
console.log("Hello");
console.log("Good Morning");

function evening() {
  console.log("Good Evening");
};

module.exports = evening;

This is the code in the first JS file. I only want to execute the "evening" function here. But when I use the require function in the other JS file, all the code of the first JS file gets excuted. Why is that?
const greetings = require("./module1.js");

greetings();

I thought if we use the module.exports object, only the assigned function/object/literal is exported.

Not sure why this question is modded down. It's a new programmer demonstrating good intellectual curiosity and it doesn't seem to be a duplicate.

Does this answer your question? Does Importing(require) module in JS also executes whole code as well?

This question is similar to: Does Node run all the code inside required modules?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Good question!

I thought if we use the module.exports object, only the assigned function/object/literal is exported.

That's true, but the exported items being exported doesn't mean the rest of the file isn't evaluated and ran. It's entirely possible you could even export some function that uses a variable in the parent scope that isn't exposed via module.exports. That module will work because the variable has been set to whatever value it should be:
console.log("Hello");
console.log("Good Morning");
const name = 'Alex';

function evening() {
  console.log("Good Evening");
  console.log(name)
};

module.exports = evening;

This is a fairly common part of JavaScript called closures (name is 'closed' above). If we didn't run the code that isn't exported the closure wouldn't work!
